# Google Translate Api Text Store for fewer requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-translate

I have a pretty big ReactJs app with a NodeJs server, where I use Google Translate Api for changing the whole app language.
I can cache somehow in the NodeJs the translated data, but im not sure right now what to do. Any ideas what I could do? If I don't implement some store functionality the google bill will be enormous.

I would need some suggestions for storing the translated text.
I was thinking to store the translated text in a JSON file and retrieve it when an user translate the text, but here problems arise if I change the content of the text in the meantime.